# Change screen orientation Android using adb

Tags: android, adb

I want to change the orientation of my Nexus S screen. I went through the logs and came across this: I/InputReader(  220): Device reconfigured: id=6, name='Melfas MMSxxx Touchscreen', surface size is now 720x1280, mode is 1
message. Can I handle this using adb, since accelerometer is not working!!